# Laravel 5.1 update query not changing value

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel-5, sql-update

good evening,

I have run into a problem with a query update it returns no error but also doesn't update the value in the defined field users defined field. I've tried removing the foreach and adding specific elements into the query like shown below but that didn't effect the field results as well.

```
$UserUpdate = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', 3)->update(array('StockAcc' => 6));
```

Controller

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \View as View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\HTTP\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
class TransController extends BaseController
{
    public function Trans(Request $Return)
    {

        $id = $Return->input('id');
        $uid = $Return->input('uid');
        $Math = $Return->input('Math');
        $Pin = $Return->input('Pin');
        $Buy = $Return->input('Buy');
        $Sell = $Return->input('Sell');
        /*
         * Querys for DB results
         */

        $User = DB::Table('users')->where('id', $uid);
        foreach ($User as $item) {
            $Final = $Buy * $Math;
                    $NewMoney = $Final - $item->StockAcc;
                    $UserUpdate = DB::table('users')
                        ->where('id', '=', $uid)
                        ->update(array('StockAcc' => $NewMoney));

        }
    }
}
```

Route

```
 Route::get('/Display', array(
        'middleware' => 'auth',
        'uses' => 'StockController@Display'
    ));

    Route::post('/test', function(){

    });
```

View:

```
{!!Form::open(array('action' => 'TransController@Trans', 'url' => ' '))!!}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't use capital letters for variables.

Comment: I believe this is because `update` method should be used on the _model_, when accessed like `App\User::where('id', $uid)->update(['StockAcc' => $NewMoney]);` but since you're finding it using the `DB` model, I don't think it will work. Try updating like I show above...you'll need to include `use App\User` (change if needed) too.

Comment: @camelCase relevant username :P

Comment: the DB model is used directly in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries @camelCase

Comment: @CharlieBilbo I was just commenting on the capitalization issue.  You should only really be using the DB class when you don't have an associated model for that table.  Check out how to do insert/update/delete using Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete .  Much cleaner and easier to do `User::find(3)->update(['StockAcc' => 6])`

Comment: Also note that you must have either `$guarded` or `$fillable` set in the model for `update` to work. By default it is protected against mass updates.

Comment: @CharlieBilbo Do you think you are getting the results with this query: `$User = DB::Table('users')->where('id', $uid);` ? I don't think so, because `where()` returns the instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` and not the desired results. You need to add `get()` method after `where()`. Also I guess there is a typo: `DB::table()` instead of `DB::Table`, Right ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `User` model instead of calling `DB::table('users')`. Then, if you add `protected $guarded = [];` to the model, you should be able to update without issue.

In your code, you can then change `DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $uid)...` to `User::where('id', '=', $uid)...`